# I downloaded this template but it's appearing like this on my blender. What am I missing?

Tags: rendering

The template is the one shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbixwwuSY-U

This is what is appearing on my screen:
 [image]

Anyone know what's up? The rendering also comes out all funny for this. It always looks like this even when I restart the program, re-download the template, etc. Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome :). This looks a like a normal (although old) viewport preview. What exactly aren't you happy with?

Comment: If by "all funny" you mean that the render doesn't look very realistic, you may want to try the cycles render engine rather than the "Blender Render" engine. There's a drop down menu at the top of your screen shot where you can choose the rendering engine.

Comment: Thanks for the responses all. By funny, I mean the entire project doesn't render. All of the parts of it that are not golden do not render, even though it is supposed to. In the tutorial video, the platform under "fox" is golden and renders. When I render my version, it is invisible and looks like the the "fox" is floating in mid-air

Comment: Sorry guys, it turns out that the using an older version was giving me the problems as the first commenter alluded to. Thanks everyone.